# Rails ActiveRecord : How can I give custom order for has_and_belongs_to_many relationship join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

Currently, I have two classes `Theme` and `Offer` mapped by a join table `themes_offers` containing `theme_id` and `offer_id`.

I need to implement a view with custom order of offers for each theme.

So the current idea I have is to add a column on the table, and create new activerecord class mapped to the table:

```
class AddOrderToThemesOffers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    add_column :themes_offers, :order, :integer

    # mark order for each existing orders

    add_index :themes_offers, [:theme_id, :order], unique: true, name: 'index_offer_order_on_theme'
  end

  def down
    remove_index :themes_offers, 'index_offer_order_on_theme'
    remove_column :themes_offers, :order, :integer
  end
end
```

Would there be a better approach? The problem I have with this solution is that it will be difficult to implement activeadmin interface to handle the orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Rails `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship is designed to create the relationship by means of a table that has two columns only: an id for each table and nothing else, not even an id of its own. See the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

I think what you want is a `has_many :through` relationship, which will allow you to have a `themes_offers` table with additional attributes on it. Docs are [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).